# How can I animate the movement of a view or image along a curved path?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I am developing a commerce application. When I add an item to the shopping cart, I want to create an effect where an image of the item follows a curved path and ends up at the cart tab.

How can I create an animation of an image along a curve like this?

Comment: [Animated images on the iPhone](http://www.cuppadev.co.uk/animated-images-on-the-iphone-sans-memory-leaks/) Refer this link. It will help you surely. Thanks.

Answer (score 153):

To expand upon what Nikolai said, the best way to handle this is to use Core Animation to animate the motion of the image or view along a Bezier path.  This is accomplished using a CAKeyframeAnimation.  For example, I've used the following code to animate an image of a view into an icon to indicate saving (as can be seen in the [video for this application](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/picubed)):

First of all import QuartzCore header file
`#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

```
UIImageView *imageViewForAnimation = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageToAnimate];
imageViewForAnimation.alpha = 1.0f;
CGRect imageFrame = imageViewForAnimation.frame;
//Your image frame.origin from where the animation need to get start
CGPoint viewOrigin = imageViewForAnimation.frame.origin;
viewOrigin.y = viewOrigin.y + imageFrame.size.height / 2.0f;
viewOrigin.x = viewOrigin.x + imageFrame.size.width / 2.0f;

imageViewForAnimation.frame = imageFrame;
imageViewForAnimation.layer.position = viewOrigin;
[self.view addSubview:imageViewForAnimation];

// Set up fade out effect
CABasicAnimation *fadeOutAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
[fadeOutAnimation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.3]];
fadeOutAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
fadeOutAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

// Set up scaling
CABasicAnimation *resizeAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds.size"];
[resizeAnimation setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(40.0f, imageFrame.size.height * (40.0f / imageFrame.size.width))]];
resizeAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
resizeAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

// Set up path movement
CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
pathAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
pathAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
pathAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
//Setting Endpoint of the animation
CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(480.0f - 30.0f, 40.0f);
//to end animation in last tab use 
//CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake( 320-40.0f, 480.0f);
CGMutablePathRef curvedPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, viewOrigin.x, viewOrigin.y);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, endPoint.x, viewOrigin.y, endPoint.x, viewOrigin.y, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
pathAnimation.path = curvedPath;
CGPathRelease(curvedPath);

CAAnimationGroup *group = [CAAnimationGroup animation]; 
group.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
group.removedOnCompletion = NO;
[group setAnimations:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:fadeOutAnimation, pathAnimation, resizeAnimation, nil]];
group.duration = 0.7f;
group.delegate = self;
[group setValue:imageViewForAnimation forKey:@"imageViewBeingAnimated"];

[imageViewForAnimation.layer addAnimation:group forKey:@"savingAnimation"];

[imageViewForAnimation release];
```

Comment: I got it.But i want to create animation effect something like i am having big image i should get resized image to big image's center then add animation path.How to get it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but the animation above does three things: moves the image along a curved path, shrinks it as it moves so that it's tiny by the time it hits the end point, and fades it out as it moves.  You can tweak the resizing by changing the from or to values, as needed.

Comment: What do I have to include so that Xcode recognizes all the CAKey...stuff? It says it doesnt find the symbols.

Comment: You need to include what you always do for Core Animation, QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h, and link against the QuartzCore framework.

Comment: That was the solution. Perfect!

Comment: i just can't get what is viewOrigin in your code. it has not been declared. is it CGPoint?

Comment: I get it. Thanks, @Brad Larson. The viewOrigin must be the original position of the image view to be animated.

Comment: @BradLarson I know this an older question but Can you please explain what I need to define viewOrigin as?:) Thanks!

Comment: @BradLarson I try to use your Code but it crash because of Bad Access Exception i think the problem because of CAKeyframeAnimation can you try it on ios8

Answer (score 4):

The way to animate along CGPath using `UIView.animateKeyframes` (Swift 4)

```
private func animateNew() {

   let alphaFrom: CGFloat = 1
   let alphaTo: CGFloat = 0.3
   let sizeFrom = CGSize(width: 40, height: 20)
   let sizeTo = CGSize(width: 80, height: 60)
   let originFrom = CGPoint(x: 40, y: 40)
   let originTo = CGPoint(x: 240, y: 480)

   let deltaWidth = sizeTo.width - sizeFrom.width
   let deltaHeight = sizeTo.height - sizeFrom.height
   let deltaAlpha = alphaTo - alphaFrom

   // Setting default values
   imageViewNew.alpha = alphaFrom
   imageViewNew.frame = CGRect(origin: originFrom, size: sizeFrom)

   // CGPath setup for calculating points on curve.
   let curvedPath = CGMutablePath()
   curvedPath.move(to: originFrom)
   curvedPath.addQuadCurve(to: originTo, control: CGPoint(x: originFrom.x,  y: originTo.y))
   let path = Math.BezierPath(cgPath: curvedPath, approximationIterations: 10)

   // Calculating timing parameters
   let duration: TimeInterval = 0.7
   let numberOfKeyFrames = 16
   let curvePoints = Math.Easing.timing(numberOfSteps: numberOfKeyFrames, .easeOutQuad)

   UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: [.calculationModeCubic], animations: {
      // Iterating curve points and adding key frames
      for point in curvePoints {
         let origin = path.point(atPercentOfLength: point.end)
         let size = CGSize(width: sizeFrom.width + deltaWidth * point.end,
                           height: sizeFrom.height + deltaHeight * point.end)
         let alpha = alphaFrom + deltaAlpha * point.end
         UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: TimeInterval(point.start), relativeDuration: TimeInterval(point.duration)) {
            self.imageViewNew.frame = CGRect(origin: origin, size: size)
            self.imageViewNew.alpha = alpha
         }
      }
   }, completion: nil)
}
```

File: `Math.Easing.swift`

```
// Inspired by: RBBAnimation/RBBEasingFunction.m: https://github.com/robb/RBBAnimation/blob/master/RBBAnimation/RBBEasingFunction.m
extension Math { public struct Easing { } }

extension Math.Easing {

   public enum Algorithm: Int {
      case linear, easeInQuad, easeOutQuad, easeInOutQuad
   }

   @inline(__always)
   public static func linear(_ t: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
      return t
   }

   @inline(__always)
   public static func easeInQuad(_ t: CGFloat) -> CGFloat  {
      return t * t
   }

   @inline(__always)
   public static func easeOutQuad(_ t: CGFloat) -> CGFloat  {
      return t * (2 - t)
   }

   @inline(__always)
   public static func easeInOutQuad(_ t: CGFloat) -> CGFloat  {
      if t < 0.5 {
         return 2 * t * t
      } else {
         return -1 + (4 - 2 * t) * t
      }
   }
}

extension Math.Easing {

   public struct Timing {

      public let start: CGFloat
      public let end: CGFloat
      public let duration: CGFloat

      init(start: CGFloat, end: CGFloat) {
         self.start = start
         self.end = end
         self.duration = end - start
      }

      public func multiplying(by: CGFloat) -> Timing {
         return Timing(start: start * by, end: end * by)
      }
   }

   public static func process(_ t: CGFloat, _ algorithm: Algorithm) -> CGFloat {
      switch algorithm {
      case .linear:
         return linear(t)
      case .easeInQuad:
         return easeInQuad(t)
      case .easeOutQuad:
         return easeOutQuad(t)
      case .easeInOutQuad:
         return easeInOutQuad(t)
      }
   }

   public static func timing(numberOfSteps: Int, _ algorithm: Algorithm) -> [Timing] {
      var result: [Timing] = []
      let linearStepSize = 1 / CGFloat(numberOfSteps)
      for step in (0 ..< numberOfSteps).reversed() {
         let linearValue = CGFloat(step) * linearStepSize
         let processedValue = process(linearValue, algorithm) // Always in range 0 ... 1
         let lastValue = result.last?.start ?? 1
         result.append(Timing(start: processedValue, end: lastValue))
      }
      result = result.reversed()
      return result
   }
}
```

File: `Math.BezierPath.swift`. Look on this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50782971/1418981

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can animate a UIView's center property using a CAKeyframeAnimation. See the [CoreAnimation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) programming guide.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 version similar to ObjC example from original response.

```
class KeyFrameAnimationsViewController: ViewController {

   let sampleImage = ImageFactory.image(size: CGSize(width: 160, height: 120), fillColor: .blue)

   private lazy var imageView = ImageView(image: sampleImage)
   private lazy var actionButton = Button(title: "Animate").autolayoutView()

   override func setupUI() {
      view.addSubviews(imageView, actionButton)
      view.backgroundColor = .gray
   }

   override func setupLayout() {
      LayoutConstraint.withFormat("|-[*]", actionButton).activate()
      LayoutConstraint.withFormat("V:|-[*]", actionButton).activate()
   }

   override func setupHandlers() {
      actionButton.setTouchUpInsideHandler { [weak self] in
         self?.animate()
      }
   }

   private func animate() {

      imageView.alpha = 1
      let isRemovedOnCompletion = false

      let sizeFrom = CGSize(width: 40, height: 20)
      let sizeTo = CGSize(width: 80, height: 60)
      let originFrom = CGPoint(x: 40, y: 40)
      let originTo = CGPoint(x: 240, y: 480)

      imageView.frame = CGRect(origin: originFrom, size: sizeFrom)
      imageView.layer.position = originFrom

      // Set up fade out effect
      let fadeOutAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
      fadeOutAnimation.toValue = 0.3
      fadeOutAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
      fadeOutAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = isRemovedOnCompletion

      // Set up scaling
      let resizeAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds.size")
      resizeAnimation.toValue = sizeTo
      resizeAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
      resizeAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = isRemovedOnCompletion

      // Set up path movement
      let pathAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
      pathAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
      pathAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
      pathAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = isRemovedOnCompletion

      // Setting Endpoint of the animation to end animation in last tab use
      let curvedPath = CGMutablePath()
      curvedPath.move(to: originFrom)
      // About curves: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/core-graphics-part-4-a-path-a-path/
      curvedPath.addQuadCurve(to: originTo, control: CGPoint(x: originFrom.x,  y: originTo.y))
      pathAnimation.path = curvedPath

      let group = CAAnimationGroup()
      group.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
      group.isRemovedOnCompletion = isRemovedOnCompletion
      group.animations = [fadeOutAnimation, pathAnimation, resizeAnimation]
      group.duration = 0.7
      group.setValue(imageView, forKey: "imageViewBeingAnimated")

      imageView.layer.add(group, forKey: "savingAnimation")
   }
}
```