# Why can't I do any CABasicAnimation or Keyframe animation stuff?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, core-animation, cabasicanimation

For some reason Xcode tells me that it doesn't find symbols as soon as I use something like kCAFillModeForwards. There must be a library or class that I have to include...but which one? The normal Core Animation stuff works fine like [myView beginAnimations...]. What's the trick to get the more sophisticated animation stuff to work?

I've included in the .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface TestClass : UIView {

}
// ...
```

I run this code:

```
- (void)testAnimation {
    CABasicAnimation *fadeInAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    [fadeInAnimation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]];
    fadeInAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    fadeInAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    // other stuff deleted to limit error possibilities...should at least compile
}
```

This happens when I build (did clean up lots of times), 2 Errors:

```
    cd "/Users/thanks/Desktop/Thanks/iPhone Development/TestApp"
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.5
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.0 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.2.1.sdk "-L/Users/thanks/Desktop/Thanks/iPhone Development/TestApp/build/Debug-iphonesimulator" "-F/Users/thanks/Desktop/Thanks/iPhone Development/TestApp/build/Debug-iphonesimulator" -filelist "/Users/thanks/Desktop/Thanks/iPhone Development/TestApp/build/TestApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/TestApp.LinkFileList" -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -o "/Users/thanks/Desktop/Thanks/iPhone Development/TestApp/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestApp.app/TestApp"
Undefined symbols:
  ".objc_class_name_CABasicAnimation", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@CABasicAnimation in TestClassTestClass.o
  "_kCAFillModeForwards", referenced from:
      _kCAFillModeForwards$non_lazy_ptr in TestClass.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
      ".objc_class_name_CABasicAnimation", referenced from:
          literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@CABasicAnimation in TestClass.o
      "_kCAFillModeForwards", referenced from:
          _kCAFillModeForwards$non_lazy_ptr in TestClass.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It says **Undefined symbols:**

Must I include some framework?

I have already included:

CoreGraphics.framework
Foundation.framework
UIKit.framework

When I remove all the code, but import QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h, then I don't get any error. So I bet that import works, but not sure.

**SOLVED**

I missed to include the QuartzCore framework!!

Comment: Perhaps instead of asking this question, you could have kept to the responses in the comments here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142727/how-can-i-animate-the-movement-of-a-view-or-image-along-a-curved-path/1143095#1143095

Comment: If you wrote this to have a clear question with a clear answer, let me tell you: Your plan failed!

Comment: You should award the answer to Jules.

Answer (score 7):

Are you importing quartz in your header?

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

QuartzCore includes the CAAnimation headers

Comment: Yes, I included it. Doesn't help. I'll update the question with more details.

Comment: Looks like this actually was the problem according to your 'SOLVED" comment in the qustion. No? If so, you should award the question to Jason.

Answer (score 7):

Probably you did not include the Quartz framework in your project.

To do so, choose your application target, go to the **Build Phases** tab and then under **Link Binary With Libraries** add the **QuartzCore.framework**.