# How would I implement animation along a path using the iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, core-animation

i am developing game application for iphone.In my application there is one object(fly).In my application this object move straight forwared using animation but i want to move object realistic.so path should be curve.please advice me about my question.

Edit:how can I create path with arc like flying an object from one place to another using curves...?

Comment: Have a look at CAKeyframeAnimation, thats the way to do such things.

Answer (score 4):

For example code that performs an animation along a curved path, you can consult [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142727/how-can-i-animate-the-movement-of-a-view-or-image-along-a-curved-path/1143095#1143095) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142727/how-can-i-animate-the-movement-of-a-view-or-image-along-a-curved-path).  As Till suggests, you'll want to use a CAKeyframeAnimation with a Core Graphics curved path set to the animation's path property.

Answer (score 3):

I created a tutorial that includes a working example of animating a view object (a UImageView) along a curved path, and posted it on GitHub. You can find it here:

[Core Animation demo](https://github.com/DuncanMC/iOS-CAAnimation-group-demo)