# Slingshot action (movement) without cocos-2d

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, game-physics, angle

I want to create a game in which the sling shot will be used like in angry birds or sling shot game. I want to ask can is this possible to make the slingshot action like it throws at object in the angle with out cocos-2d. Please help me how should I proceed with this because I do not much on cocos 2d.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must make a method which will find the points to make a path from initial point to end point.

for that you need to use some dynamics concept.

after that you can implement animation of view along "path".[How would I implement animation along a path using the iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741402/how-would-i-implement-animation-along-a-path-using-the-iphone-sdk)

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just go with buying this [starter kit](http://cartoonsmartkits.com/angryninjas_kit.php5) if you want to avoid deep dig into cocos2D.
It's got good dynamic features with lots of documentation.

Answer (score -1):

You can UIView animation alternative of Cocos2d

Comment: I also know that UIViewAnimation is provided, but I need some start point help regarding the concept and some code.