# How do I animate a UIImageView along an arc?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-animation

How do I animate a UIImageView in an arc, starting at point A, passing through point C, and ending at point B?

Comment: Is this homework? If yes, what have you tried?

Comment: This is asking something similar to this question: [How do I translate parabolically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886158/how-do-i-translate-parabolically), so the answer I provide there might apply here.

Answer (score 1):

You should animate the `UIImageView`'s `layer` property with a `CAKeyframeAnimation`, specifying a `CGPathRef` for the `path` property.

You can read more about key frame animation in Apple's documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Animation_Types_Timing/Articles/PropertyAnimations.html).