# cocoa - animate views along custom paths

Tags: iphone, cocoa, animation, touch

Is this possible? maybe using the CGAffineTransformations?

More specifically, my objective is to move an imageView along a parabolic trajectory using only an animation.

Maybe someone can point me in the right direction?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps

[How do I translate parabolically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886158/how-do-i-translate-parabolically)

[How can I animate the movement of a view or image along a curved path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142727/how-can-i-animate-the-movement-of-a-view-or-image-along-a-curved-path)