# Animation along path - Completion method called too early

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, quartz-core

I'd like to implement an animation along a rounded path and fire a completion function as soon as the animation has ended.

Thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886158/how-do-i-translate-parabolically) I figured out how to use a **CAKeyframeAnimation** with a **CGMutablePathRef** to perform the animation along a path.

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
pathAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
pathAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
pathAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
pathAnimation.duration = 1.0;

CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(self.boardReference.view.bounds.size.width/2,self.boardReference.view.bounds.size.height/2);
CGMutablePathRef curvedPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, endPoint.x, self.view.center.y, endPoint.x, self.view.center.y, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
pathAnimation.path = curvedPath;
CGPathRelease(curvedPath);
[self.view.layer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"curvedPath"];

[self addNewCardAtPoint:endPoint]; //This should only be launched after the animation has been finished
```

Problem: My method *addNewCardAtPoint* should only be called **after** the animation has been completed. Currently the process is not blocking so the method is called more or less simultaneously.

At the first view the animateWithDuration function seems to better suited as it has defined blocks for the animation and the completion action. But simply adding the CAKeyframeAnimation to the animations block has basically the same result, immediate execution of the completion block.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.8
                 animations:^{
                     NSLog(@"-Animate on curved path to end point-");
                     ... //how perform the same path based animation here?
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [self addNewCardAtPoint:self.view.center];
                 }
 ];
```

How can I fire a complete function only after the animation along the curved path has been completed?

Answer (score 0):

When a `CAAnimation` is done, it will call the `animationDidStop:finished:` method on its delegate.