# Animation with UIViews - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

Currently, I figured out how to animate an image that is in my UIViewController:

```
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo.png"];

    CALayer *logoLayer = [CALayer layer];
    logoLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    logoLayer.position = CGPointMake(300, 216);
    logoLayer.contents = (id)image.CGImage;
    CAKeyframeAnimation *moveAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    moveAnimation.path = path.CGPath;
    moveAnimation.duration = 2.0f;
    [logoLayer addAnimation:moveAnimation forKey:@"moveAnimation"]; 

    CAAnimationGroup *animationGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
    animationGroup.duration = 2.0f;
    animationGroup.autoreverses = NO;
    animationGroup.repeatCount = 1; //HUGE_VALF
    [animationGroup setAnimations:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: moveAnimation, nil]];

    [logoLayer addAnimation:animationGroup forKey:@"animationGroup"];
```

But this is based on a logoLayer, which is an image. How could I animate something like this but for a UIView? Such as a UIButton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, rather than using `CAAnimation`s on `CALayer`s, you can use [`UIView` animation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW1). There are ways to set animation curve, delay, repeat, reversal, and so on using the block-based animation [API](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) or the old delegate-based API.

As for your specific case of the `CAKeyframeAnimation`, you can try the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887156/resize-and-move-a-uiview-with-core-animation-cakeyframeanimation).