# iPhone How to get photo taken effect like in camera application?

Tags: iphone, camera, core-animation

I am talking about that effect when user presses button to take photo, it shrinks and moves to toolbar? How is this achieved in general?

Answer (score 0):

so the shrink animation is achived by

```
 [UIView beginAnimations:@"animationShrink" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:kSlideInAnimationDuration];

    flipFlopContainer.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView    setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(shrinkAnimationFinished:)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

after this animation in shrinkAnimationFinished method you need to define a path to follow and change the position of your view accroding to that path.

See the following thread for that animation

[Resize and move a UIView with Core Animation (CAKeyFrameAnimation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887156/resize-and-move-a-uiview-with-core-animation-cakeyframeanimation)

Comment: Since he would need to animate the position along a path using Core Animation it would be better to do the transform with Core Animation as well and not mix the different animation API:s.

Answer (score 0):

You can create this by both scaling (applying a transform) and moving (animating the position)  of the image.

I wrote about a similar animation (the Open in Background animation from Safari on iPhone) in [this blog post](http://ronnqvist.tumblr.com/post/23234805389/unobtrusive-hints-of-joy). Not all of the code is necessary but some part of it will be useful for the animation you are trying to do.

---

You should

- Calculate the scale factor to make the image the appropriate size
- Calculate the path you want to animate the image along.
- Animate a scale with the calculated scale factor
- Animate a position animation along the path (using a CAKeyframeAnimation)

Since you are doing two animations at once you could benefit from using a CAAnimationGroup.

Since you are animating down to a toolbar which probably is another part of the view hierarchy than where the image is you may need to use method like

```
- (CGRect)convertRect:(CGRect)rect toView:(UIView *)view
```

and

```
- (CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point toView:(UIView *)view
```

To translate coordinates between the different views.