# Moving image along predetermined path?

Tags: iphone, image, animation, sdk, path

Is it possible to set an image into motion along a predetermined path with the push of a button in iphone SDK?  I'm not looking for anything fancy.  I working on a simple concept, but this would save a lot of animation work.

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142727/how-can-i-animate-the-movement-of-a-view-or-image-along-a-curved-path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can animate any CALayer along a path by creating a `CAKeyframeAnimation` and assigning a `CGPath` to its `path` property. See [this blog post by Bill Dudney](http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/entry/keyframe_animation) for an example.