# Draw a curve in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I am developing a game app in which a curve(Bezier) is required on the basis of theta provided by user and this will be in animated format. But i am not aware of openGL. Then how can i do it programatically?

Comment: Are you asking how to animate an object along a curve?  If so, my answer to this question may be what you're looking for: [How can I animate the movement of a view or image along a curved path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142727/how-can-i-animate-the-movement-of-a-view-or-image-along-a-curved-path)

Comment: What is viewOrigin in your post. Its shows undeclared in my code.

Comment: `viewOrigin` is, as the name would indicate, the current origin of the view.  It can be obtained by reading the `frame` property of the view, then grabbing the `origin` component of that.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`UIBezierPath`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the [Quartz](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_overview/dq_overview.html) drawing guide.

Comment: Have a look at the Quartz drawing guide (which I've linked to) and read about all the things you can use for drawing in iOS.