# What is the role of key path in Core Animation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation

I'm getting acquanted with Core Animation and trying to implement simple movement along a curve line. i've found really helpful piece of code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142727/how-can-i-animate-the-movement-of-a-view-or-image-along-a-curved-path)

There is a line there:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
```

Why do we need this property named keyPath? What is its role? The code works only if use the proposed NSString @"position" and nothing else. So is it a built-in constant string? It doesn't look so. Hope you see my confusion. Can you please explain in plain language how do i manage this keyPath property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- KeyPath says which animatable attribute is going to modified to
  create animation effect
- You can use any of the animatable property as keypath
- You can find them in the header file(say CALayer) on which you
  apply animation

> ```
>  /* The position in the superlayer that the anchor point of the layer's
>   bounds rect is aligned to. Defaults to the zero point. **Animatable**. */
> ```

```
   @property CGPoint position;
```

- Not a constant String , it is attribute name

Answer (score 1):

CABasicAnimation and CAKeyframeAnimation are inherited from CAPropertyAnimation. Both use its **animationWithKeyPath:** method.

KeyPath has to contain **Animatable Properties**. Find them here [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20111010140734/http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/AnimProps.html)