# iPhone keypaths for layer animations?

Tags: iphone, core-animation, calayer

I have a layer and i would like to modify its size. But there is something that bugs me. Is modifying its transform property, same as making basic animation on layer. Is this:

```
layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.5, 0.5, 1);
```

same as:

```
CABasicAnimation *scale = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath: @"transform.scale"];
scale.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:startScale];
scale.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:endScale];
[layer addAnimation:scale forKey:@"animateScale"];
```

Also, is there some list where I can see what keypaths are available for basic animations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it header file . It will be noted as Animatable. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9717421/641062) answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the results are very similar.

The first approach uses the implicit animation feature of CALayers.

Using a CABasicAnimation gives you a lot more control and other options, at the cost of more setup.