# Move CALayer via UIBezierPath

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation, calayer

I have a layer that will move from point A to point B on a UIBezierPath. 
I have found a lot of samples those are refers to CAAnimation and UIBezierPath. 
But I need to move my layer only from specified point to another on bezier path.

[image]

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just figure out the path segment and use that as the animation path

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142727/how-can-i-animate-the-movement-of-a-view-or-image-along-a-curved-path

Comment: have you found the solution ?

Answer (score 4):

Hope this will be helpful.

```
UIBezierPath *trackPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
.
.
.
CAKeyframeAnimation *anim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
anim.path = trackPath.CGPath;
anim.repeatCount = 1;
anim.duration = 2.0;
[layerToAnimate addAnimation:anim forKey:@"pathGuide"];
```

Answer (score 3):

If your bezier path is a circle or even a half circle, you could just skip the path and instead add the point to a larger square layer. Set the point to be a fixed distance from the center of that larger square layer. Then you can just rotate the larger layer on the z axis around the center whatever number of degrees you need it to move. Seems it would simplify things a bit, though I'm not sure exactly what else you need it to do.

Answer (score 2):

i'd been looking to do something like this and fount this tutorial, it shows how to follow a specific path. It works with a car (a CALayer) and a UIBezierpath as the race track and is solved in this order:

Defining the path the car should follow (in this case your BezierPath)
Drawing the black line that defines the track; (N/A)
Drawing the white dashed center-line of the track; (N/A)
Creating the layer defining the car; (your Layer)
Animating the car along the path. (What your asked!)

You can check the reference Post here:
http://nachbaur.com/2011/01/07/core-animation-part-4/

Also you can download the source code here:
http://cdn5.nachbaur.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/CALayerAnimTest.zip?25881d

hope this helps!

regards,

Jorge.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but thats not i'm looking for. I'm looking to move between two points in bezier path. Not complete path.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please edit your answer to correct this, then flag your post to request un-deletion